# How to normalize Excel cell data

Tags: regex, excel

I am getting the data from an external source, and I need to normalize the cells.
like this:

```
A

32.1342244,31.1322214,0
35.12331299999999,12.14324553333333,0
..
..
```

And I would like Row A to be in the form of two numbers (instead of three) and with the mantissa with 8 digits max. so the above data would look like this:

```
A

32.1342244,31.1322214
35.12331299,12.14324553
..
..
```

How can I do this? Is there a way to use a regexp for that?
Can this be done in a way to simply sanitize the data and not copy it from one place to another?

Comment: You can do it in place, but I would not recommend it. If the three numbers are in the same Column A, then they are not numbers, but text. So just write a formula to split the contents of column A in two columns B and C and eventually join them back in column D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this tiny macro:

```
Sub Normalize()
    Dim r As Range, ary
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Value, ",")
        ary(0) = Format(ary(0), "0.00000000")
        ary(1) = Format(ary(1), "0.00000000")
        r.Value = ary(0) & "," & ary(1)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely answers my question! Is Macro, the only way of solving this problem?

Comment: It is do-able with formulas. but it would be complex.

Comment: formulas would need copying the content to somewhere else, and wouldn't be able to leave the data where it is right?

Comment: @Jackson ,,,,,,,,you are correct! ...............the macro can fix your data in"in place."